# Excel 2010 ActiveX Controls No Longer Working After Windows Updates

Tags: excel, activex, activexobject, vba

So at work I ran into this issue after I installed the most recent Windows 7 updates (including Microsoft Office 2010 updates) - the date up the update was today (Dec 12, 2014).

After the update, I opened my macro enabled workbook in Excel 2010 and basically anything that referenced ActiveX controls (checkboxes, buttons) no longer worked. My auto_open was checking checkboxes and couldn't run... it kept erroring at the first checkbox check.  The buttons are also no longer clickable.

Before you say it, I have checked my trust settings and allowed all ActiveX and Macros, but no change.  If anyone has any advice, I'm all ears.  Due to me not being an admin, I cannot due too many things as far as Windows goes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We had this somewhat shocking issue yesterday on several machines with Excel 2007.

By rolling back Security updates for office one by one, we determined that this was being caused by update `KB2596927` from 9 December 2014 - [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2596927)

After this update, not only did many macro-enabled worksheets break down upon activating macros due to their ActiveX controls being killed, but also no classic ActiveX controls (button, checkbox, etc.) could be inserted into a blank workbook any longer!

CONFIRM AS SOLVED: I can confirm that the answer to delete the file `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel8.0\MSForms.exd` has worked for me!

Thank you guys!

Here is more information on [EXD files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290537)

This was resolved also in another post on this [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled)

Answer (score 2):

Resolved issue !

- Close Excel
- Rename or delete this file (at your own risk) :
    C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel8.0\MSForms.exd

It would be rebuild after Excel reopens. My ActiveX et macros are working good !

Have a good day !

Cracki

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix and workaround use this tool:

http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9875022

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025036

Basically remove all “.exd” files which represent the cache of the forms.