# VBA Excel + COM on Windows 7 x64: ActiveX Component Can't Create Object

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I am having an extraordinarily hard time trying to integrate a basic Class Library made in VB .NET 4.5 using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition to my Excel 2013 VBA Module.

I have tried countless solutions and have followed the following steps to get here:

1. I created a basic Class Library (see below).

[image]

2. I set the properties "Make assembly COM-visible" and "Register for COM interop" to true (see [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-net-class-library-excel-vba-40349.html)).
3. I've added a reference to my Excel project. Note* I have to explicitly find the name of my class library in the list of possible references I have to make, check it off, and then click OK in the references window.

VBA Intellisense recognizes the code:

[image]

Which means my class library is being properly referenced. However, when I run the code I get Error 429: ActiveX component can't create object.

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I fix this?
2. What can I do to make my class library work with as little friction as possible for users on other computers. Does everyone have to register the DLL and then import the reference or can they just download my Excel sheet and have everything imported?

Comment: Are you getting the active x error on the dev machine, or the target?

Comment: Dev machine. But I would also like to support other target machines.

Comment: Is it possible that you're having [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled) issue?

Comment: @tsurantino I think the problem here is the Target Platform in the Debug tab (right click solution then Properties and then select Debug tab on the left) is set to 32 bit or ANY platrform rather than 64 bit for a 64 bit office