# Using ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1" causes 1004 cannot insert object error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a combobox in Excel (2010) using **VBA** but I keep getting the error message **1004 cannot insert object.**

Even in a new workbook and copying directly from MS Dev Centre -

**Worksheets(1).OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1" produces the error**.

Same with any variation of "Forms.XXXX.1".

If I substitute "WordDocument" it works OK.

Can anyone help please?

STOP PRESS

Deleting all .exd files from my temp folders appears to have done the trick.  No help whatsoever from Microsoft of course!

Comment: You may want to use a Form's control (`ActiveSheet.Listboxes.Add()` ) rather than an ActiveX because [ActiveX are currently now working in Excel.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27411399/2140173)