# "Compile error: Method or data member not found" with previously working code

Tags: excel, vba, compilation, xlsm

As the title suggests, I'm getting the above error with code that was working 6 days ago.

```
Code since omitted - apologies
```

DurationCombo is an ActiveX ComboBox which resides on Sheet1.

I can provide an image of the ComboBox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM7YD.png

I've seen all of the information regarding the Microsoft Updates and removed the anomaly yet this problem has since returned.

**EDIT:** I am also unable to add ActiveX controls to **any** Excel workbook. Bizarre, this one is!

**EDIT 2:** It may be an option to move from ActiveX controls to Form ComboBoxes. However, I have issues when converting. Any help with this would also be great - if it's possible!

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error if the `DurationCombo` ComboBox does not exist on Sheet1. Are you sure this box is named correctly and that it is still on Sheet1?

Comment: 100% positive it's there. And, it's line "With Sheet1.DurationCombo". I've added to the main question about further diagnostics.

Comment: Did you also confirm what it is named? If it was copied and pasted at any point, it would have been automatically renamed.

Comment: Just saw your edit. I also get the error if I disable ActiveX controls. Go to the Trust Center in Excel Options and make sure that "Disable all controls without notification" is not selected.

Comment: Just been in, clicked design mode and the ComboBox and yes, "DurationCombo" is its name. The edit would lead me to believe it's something else! Power cycle imminent, I'm at wit's end.

Comment: Double-checked the ActiveX controls settings, it was second from the bottom (implying it will ask before execution). I've set this to never ask for the purpose of testing and still nada, I'm afraid.

Comment: When you say you are not able to add ActiveX controls, are you getting an error message?

Comment: Just a mere "Cannot insert object"

Comment: That's the same error I got after the Microsoft update that messed up the ActiveX functionality. Did you remove **all** the files as described in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled)?

Comment: Yes - I only have the .exd within the Excel8.0 branch. I deleted it, rebooted and then opened the Excel spreadsheet to no avail.

Comment: Try these two answers and let me know if you're still having the problem: [Answer 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled/27515060#27515060), [Answer 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled/27495533#27495533)

Comment: Tried them both. No luck. Also, fyi, I've just powered up my desktop (a second machine) and the program works flawlessly on here.

Comment: One more: [Answer 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled/28193143#28193143). If this one doesn't work, you may need to go directly to Microsoft on this one.

Comment: I have none of them currently installed. I'll go to the IT department at work, see if they can roll my machine back to the 6th. It worked then. I had a shedload of updates yesterday so I guess it might be that. May I say thank you for your persistence; some times it's nice just having someone there who understands the situation.

Comment: No problem! I hope you get it figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got rid of KB2553154 (installed 11th February 2015) and success! Good luck to anyone else with this issue. My recommendation would be to research and uninstall any suspect Microsoft updates. That's the only thing that solved it for me (twice).

Comment: Make sure to mark your answer as the correct answer. Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and used **Microsoft Fix it 51029**  mentioned here:
 [ActiveX](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025036/EN-US)

Comment: Tried this to no avail, either :(