# Using VBA range commands with ActiveX buttons in other sheets

Tags: vba, range, activex

while building up a user Interface I made use of ActiveX buttons in VBA2010. I wrote the Macros first, checked them, then copied them into the ActiceX button code.

The macro then crashes at a range command of another sheet. To test it I separated the commands:

```
Sheets("Data").Visible = xlSheetVisible 
Sheets("Data").Select                   
Columns("O:O").Select         ' The code crashes here
```

As a result I get a 1004 runtime error.
I found a similar topic which seems to be unsolved aswell.

[Unable to Execute Macro With ActiveX Controls (Excel VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746724/unable-to-execute-macro-with-activex-controls-excel-vba)

Help is well appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select is not recommended.Modify your code to

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = Sheets("Data")
 ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
 ws.Select
 With ws
 .Columns("O:O").Select
 End With
```

Comment: Click on the check mark if that answers your question.

Comment: Will do so. Thanks :)