# Excel Deployment - resizing and other component display issues

Tags: excel, vba, layout, deployment, activex

I have been working on a project in excel for a while and am having problems deploying it to my client. We have (exactly) the same version of excel but when he opens the file the sizing of the components is all wrong. Please see the screenshots below:

[image: Design mode off]

When he turns on design mode or clicks and holds the vertical scroll bar, the issue corrects itself for the most part:

[image: Design mode on]

But when compared to the original there are still issues, such as the "Rental Start" and "Rental End" labels.

[image: My side]

I should also mention that this problem is not isolated to this project. We had some issues with a different one, as well, but never made the connection between design mode and couldn't figure it out. I have tried my IntegralHeight property per a forum post somewhere, as well as double checking that my components are not set to size with cells. Does anyone know why this might be occurring? He has windows 8.1 and I have 7, if that could be the difference.

Note: All controls are ActiveX controls.

Comment: Do the controls work as expected?  I somewhat recall an ActiveX workbook I use looking very off due to the December 2014 update that broke ActiveX for a bit.  It was sizing based on VBA code that never had a chance to run since the controls were broken.  It was obvious something else was wrong though because none of the controls worked! Details on that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled