# Excel giving "System Error &H80004005 (-2147467259). Unspecified error" message

Tags: vba, excel, activex, system-error

Everytime I load up my Excel document, it repeatedly shows up with the message from the title. The two options are OK and Help. help opens Office Help which is useless for anything. Clicking OK displays another message saying "Compile error: Out of memory." with OK and Help buttons. Clicking OK brings up VBEditor with no debug line selected and no macro popped up either for that matter. Eventually, after it repeats that and complains 20 (exaggeration) more times (I think that's due to having a lot of duplicate code for ActiveX controls on each sheet). It highlights the first line (the Sub declaration) of the code below.

```
Private Sub ComboBox4_Change()
Range("B3") = ActiveSheet.ComboBox4.text
End Sub
```

Now this is dealing with an ActiveX ComboBox. Opening a file from an earlier date will give no errors. It's like after a certain date, it just refuses to work with it. And get this, it's only happening on one computer. The files are saved on a network drive, which shouldn't be causing an error.

Comment: A Shot in the dark: is `Comctl32.dll` registered on your machine?

Comment: I used "RegSvr32 comctl32.dll" in the Run window and it gave an error saying that it was loaded, but the entry-point DllRegisterService was not found.

Comment: yes. you have to register it using Admin rights :)

Comment: Extract the comdlg32.ocx to your the Windows\System32 folder or Windows\SysWOW64. Then right click on CMD->Run as administrator and then register from there

Comment: I don't have admin rights as this is a company computer.

Comment: Well I think that is the problem then.. See if you can ask an IT guy to register it for you

Comment: I also don't have the .ocx. Just the dll. And besides, why would it work on a previous file that has activeX controls as well?

Comment: Do both files have exactly the same activex controls?

Comment: There was also [this problem last December](http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2014/12/11/forms-controls-stop-working-after-december-2014-updates-.aspx). With Excel closed, delete the following files `del %temp%\vbe\*.exd

del %temp%\excel8.0\*.exd

del %appdata%\microsoft\forms\*.exd

del %appdata%\microsoft\local\*.exd`

Comment: @ChipsLetten: yeah i had forgotten about exds :P

Comment: Yes same controls. Perhaps I may have modified some code, but I can't believe it would ruin it somehow... I'll try deleting the exds (if they don't require amin).

Comment: Related to @ChipsLetten, here is [the SO question on that issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled).

Comment: Deleting the temp .exds still made the error show on startup, but no errors are showing anymore when a macro is run.

Comment: Even after deleting the .exds, the problem remains. I can open a file, click OK for the 10 popops and run macros. One thing I can not do is save it, which is something that I need. It says to use less data or close out programs because it is "out of memory". I have about 2GB RAM available (4GB out of 6GB in use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was that I had a user form with an acrobat reader display control (like an iframe, but for PDFs). I didn't have this reference or control on that specific computer and it freaked out. Not 100% sure, but the problem no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost 100% certain I found a solution to this issue. It may have caused issues for someone else 4 years ago, but it caused issues for me today and I wanted to contribute my answer for anyone else running into the same problem.

I had enabled an "Additional Control" in the Controls Toolbox for Windows Media Player. I think when it loaded in a video file, it overran the memory. This is when I started panicking (company computer and all) and Googling and came across this and a few other articles without a real, fast fix.

The hunch: Once that video file was attempted to be loaded in RAM memory (because that's how Userforms work) it locked up all the memory Excel would allow before throwing all the errors.

What I tried from other posts in various places: I rebooted a few times (before Googling, even). I tried the Quick Repair of Office from Add/Remove programs, that didn't work. (I'm using Office 2016.)

So, what worked? I had the idea that maybe I could disable all ActiveX from loading in my file, and Googled that. I got: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-activex-settings-in-office-files-f1303e08-a3f8-41c5-a17e-b0b8898743ed and proceeded to disable all ActiveX controls in Excel. I closed the file out. Can't recall if I closed Excel but I probably did.

Then I loaded up my file. (ActiveX is totally disabled at this time.) No errors! I went to VBA (ALT + F11), opened my UserForm, and the video I had inserted and could not remove was just... gone. I saved the file. I closed the file.

I opened Excel. I re-enabled ActiveX in the Trust Center. I opened my file. Still, no more video on my UserForm (I didn't need it anyway) and no "Unspecified" (memory) errors! And, I can save again!

I hope this solution persists... if not I've got some "splainin' " to do. So far, I'm designing and using the Userform, and saving the file, with no issues whatsoever. I think it worked!

Comment: Thank you man you saved me a loss of all my work! In my case I tried to add "System Monitor Control" in the toolbox and it did it to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a very similar problem with WindowsMediaPlayer (WMP) ActiveX control that I have in a Form. Some computers with office 2016 are giving this error code (usless the help button), this is the first post I have found about something similar with WMP, and I found it after searching for this error on ActiveX controls...

So my solution was to go to VBA (alt+F11), right clic on form that has the activex control and then remove it witohout exporting.

The big problem is, that for me, this form is the most important part of the application.

I have no mor information, if I find something I'll come back to post feedback.

Comment: Make sure all computers have the same references enabled. On the computers that work, go to VBA (Alt+F11), Tools, References, and take note of the checked ones. Go to a computer that doesn't work and compare. Enable any that are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when trying to pull data from an access database. The query I was trying to pull from in the database was an all value query (*). Once I added the individual fields, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error, when I create a user form which has no body section(just header). (Using this method for the messages where I don't expect a user response. Like a progress bar.
Probably, any abnormality(*)or inconsistency with the user form causes this problem.

Solution: Changed the height of the user form just a few pixel.

Answer (score -1):

Just a simple trick worked for me

1. Go to Excel Options
2. Manage Excel Add-ins
3. Uncheck all and click ok