# UserForm ActiveX controls not working on new machine

Tags: excel, activex, userform, vba

I built a workbook in Excel on my old machine that has a bunch of UserForms in it.  One of the UserForms has an ActiveX spreadsheet control in it.  This allows me to enter spreadsheet data into the UserForm.  My old computer recently crashed so my IT department gave me a new machine that is running the same system (Microsoft Office 2010).  Now, when I open the spreadsheet, I get:

> Could not load some objects because they are not available on this machine.

I Googled this error and read through a number of pages.  The first thing to try was installing Microsoft Office Web Components 11.0.  Weirdly, this allows me to add a spreadsheet control to any UserForm I want to but I still cannot open the original sheet with all of its controls still in it.

Next, I tried [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled) but got no results.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library` (found as `FM20.dll`)

Hth

Comment: Weird.  When I open the file on my old machine, the box for Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library is checked as well as the one for Microsoft Office Web Components 11.0.  When I open it on the new computer, those boxes are not checked.  Even after I check them, I still have the same problem.

Comment: After checking them, you may have to exit and restart the application(s).  Also, try deleting those pesky MSForms.exd files from wherever you can find them while the app(s) are all closed, and then restart.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried both of those things and it still won't work.