# Command Button not working

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have an **Excel 2010** spreadsheet with VBA code.
When I try using it in **Excel 2013** some strange stuff happens:

The **Command Buttons** on the existing worksheets stopped working.  The **VBA code** associated to them does not run.  Not even an error message appears.

I tried adding a new Command Button to an existing worksheet, but it does not run either.

**But**, if I create a new worksheet in the spreadsheet, and add a **Command Button** in it, the button executes with no problems.

Comment: I sounds as if macro code does not have the permission to run; the workbook is untrusted. However, I'm not sure that explains why you can create a new worksheet in the same workbook and have code run from there. In any event, I'd start in Excel Option, Trust Center (Alt+F, T, T)

Comment: Thanks but I already tried the Trust Center.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Excel ActiveX Controls Disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Excel 2016 but I think I ran into a similar problem.  I put a command button into the worksheet and then the code did not run when I pressed the button.  I discovered that I was still in "Design Mode".  In the Controls group of commands in the Developer tab the "Design Mode" button was still grayed out.  I clicked it to turn off Design Mode and then the code started running when I clicked the button.  In short I was still in Design Mode (for the actual design and layout of the buttons) when I was initially trying to get the button to work.  It did not work. I exited Design Mode and then the button worked.  This may not be helpful to the person asking the question as they already had the buttons in the workbook.  However it may help someone who stumbled upon this question because they had problems getting the button to work initially.