# Excel macro to get SEPARATE graphs of many Ys with the same Xs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set in which the first column is the x but the other columns (> 50) are the Ys. There are 6 rows. I know I can plot all the Ys on the same axis in the same chart, but I need separate graphs of Y all with the same x. However, I am clueless if it is possible to have an excel macro that will allow me to plot DIFFERENT bar graphs  for as many Ys all at once. Doing it manually is a pain because I have many datasets with these dimensions. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code I used but it plotted all the bars in a single graph. Found this code online and tweaked it

```
Sheets("sheet1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
 With ActiveChart
 .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:D7")  'sets source  data for graph including labels
.SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)  'including legend
.HasTitle = True
'dimentions & location:
.Parent.Left = 47   'defines the coordinates for the left side of the chart
.Parent.Height = 300
.Parent.Width = 600
.ChartTitle.Text = "Yield by group " & intGraphStart
End With
```

[A sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPyxY.jpg)

Comment: A screenshot or depiction of your data would be helpful, as well as any attempt at the code you have tried to this point.  So is not a "Code for Me site"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure below create a chart in a separated sheet for each of the columns from `B` to `L` using column `A` as a common horizontal axis.

```
Sub Rng_Charts_Add_Multiple()
Const kChrTtl As String = "Yield by group "
Dim Wbk As Workbook, WshSrc As Worksheet
Dim rSrc As Range, Chrt As Chart
Dim sCol As String, bCol As Byte

    Rem Application Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set WshSrc = Wbk.Sheets("Sht(1)")
    Application.Goto WshSrc.Cells(1), 1
    Set rSrc = WshSrc.Cells(1).CurrentRegion

    For bCol = 2 To rSrc.Columns.Count

        Rem Add Chart in a New Sheet
        sCol = rSrc.Cells(1, bCol).Value2
        With Wbk
            On Error Resume Next
            .Sheets("Chart " & sCol).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
            Application.Goto WshSrc.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(2, 2)
            Set Chrt = .Charts.Add2(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count), NewLayout:=1)
        End With

        Rem Chart Settings
        With Chrt
            .name = "Chart " & sCol
            .ApplyLayout (1)
            .ChartTitle.Text = kChrTtl & sCol
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            .SetSourceData Source:=Union(rSrc.Columns(1), rSrc.Columns(bCol))

    End With: Next

    Rem Application Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Suggest to visit the following pages:

[Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html), [Application Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx), [Excel Objects](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Objects.html)

[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx), [For...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251601.aspx), [Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx)

[Worksheet Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194464.aspx), [ChartObjects Members (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff836747.aspx)

Comment: tried running the code you graciously provided but I keep getting the error: Compile error: Method or data member not found. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: does it highlights any line?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that! Yes, the very first line.

Comment: Sub Rng_Charts_Add_Multiple()

Comment: Ni idea... Did you copy the procedure in a new module?

Comment: That's weird... let's try this select all (Ctrl+A) in the module and comment  (Comment block) then Compile VBA project. It should compile OK. After this Uncomment all then compile again....

Comment: compiled well. after uncommenting and compiling, the error came on again.

Comment: have no idea. try changing the name of the procedure. If this does not work, could you share your file so I can look at it. The code has nothing out of the ordinary... and it seems like excel is expecting that procedure to be something else...

Comment: I found this [VBA - Compile Error - Method or Data member not Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled) Did you run any update lately?

Comment: Changing name didn't fix it either. Unfortunately, my work computer restricts where and what I can do online so I can't use file sharing extensions or systems. However, the sample I posted in my initial post is exactly how my data is arranged. I just have many more columns. You know I was also thinking it is probably my version of excel (2007), but I am unsure. I updated Java yesterday and that's all. It probably would work on my personal computer with a newer version. I will try it when I get home. The info on the link might be helpful. I will go through that as well. I'd give you a feedback

Comment: I usually have issues with R on my work computer as well. I am somewhat certain it would run on my personal computer. Appreciate the code, I will get back to you on my findings

Comment: Aren't you the best? It worked on my personal computer! I told ya! Thank you again, EEM!