# Corruption in Excel Workbook in 2016 but OK in 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I built an Excel workbook at a customer site, on their hardware, using Excel 2010. The workbook has an ActiveX button to execute macros to run a SQL stored procedure and populate a data sheet. I use the same code at all my customers. The workbook runs fine. I password protect the VBA to stop anyone changing the code.

I took my usual backup copies. When I open the workbook on my laptop, running Excel 2016, I get the

> "we found a problem with some content..."

recovery message. If I recover, it removes the button and some of the VBA code.

I have tried amending my Trust Centre settings but no difference. When I VPN into the client, the workbook onsite opens OK. However, another external party has tried opening one of the workbooks using his local 2013 version and gets the same thing.

Apparently, the CFO uses Excel for Mac so I am wondering if this is causing an issue, or whether there is something screwy going on with the versions of Excel. I have created at least 12 workbooks, all using the same code, and they all behave in the same way.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only thing I can think is to use form controls instead of ActiveX controls. I think it has something to do with Microsoft phasing out support for ActiveX controls or something like that. Hopefully somebody a little better informed can shed a bit more light on the why.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the suggestion. I will give it a try anyway, just to check.

Comment: Maybe this will be relevant to your problem and have some potential solutions. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled), it  does look like Microsoft updates at some point have broken Active X controls.

Comment: HI Clusks, tried what was suggested but still the same. Thanks for replying though

Answer (score 0):

after advice from Dave yesterday, it appears that replacing my ActiveX Control with a Form Control has done the trick. I had to amend my macro code slightly as there is no onclick option for a Form button so I created a sub that calls my various VBA chunks which is then assigned to the button.

Thanks for all the responses and advice.

Comment: Spoke too soon. For some reason, when I tested yesterday it worked, so spent the last hour changing all the workbooks to form controls instead of activex controls, copied over and they are still corrupt.