# Word 2013 HTML Form Controls not working on some PCs

Tags: forms, ms-word, controls, word-field

A colleague and I have received a Word Document by email in `docx` format.

Both my colleague and I are running Word 2013 32-bit on Windows 7.

My colleague is able to open the document and interact with the form controls.
If I expand *his* Properties Windows dropdown, I see controls like:

> - **DefaultOcxName** HTMLText
> - **DefaultOcxName1** HTMLOption
> - **DefaultOcxName2** HTMLSelect
> - **ThisDocument** Document

When I open the document on *my* PC, the controls are all "pictures" and can't be interacted with as Form controls, rendering the Form unusable. The Properties Window shows only a single entry in its dropdown:

> - **ThisDocument** Document

Is this a configuration/compatibility setting, or is there some component that my colleague has, that I don't, that allows him to open the file and use the form?

I have tried deleting the form control caches as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27453341/5757159), but it doesn't help.