# Second action button displaying in excel VBA, but I cannot select it

Tags: excel, vba, activex, commandbutton

I'm new to using VB w/ excel, so please forgive my lack of technical verbiage.

I recently received a new laptop, and transfered an excel file from my old laptop with VB setup to automatically generate reports. On the new laptop, when I click on my Active X Command Buttons, a smaller duplicate button appears. For some of these buttons, I can double click and the needed action is performed if that second button is under my mouse icon. For others (see picture), this second button displays, but when I move my mouse to get to it, it disappears.

Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: By chance are you working with the file on a second monitor? A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56265391/excel-active-x-button-cannot-be-clicked/) was asked recently. I have had the same issue.

Comment: It's why I stopped using ActiveX controls.  They have a nasty habit of moving, ghosting, growing, shrinking and generally not doing what they are told.

Comment: @Gareth couldn't agree with you more.

Comment: @BigBen That solved the problem...thank you for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select one button and use 'Tab' Key to select next one