# Combo box populated successfully yesterday but failed today

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, populate

I used a simple code to populate combo box from a list of worksheets dynamically. On Sat, the combo box was successfully populated.

On Sunday I played with the code by adding new form controls/new codes. Then suddenly the combo box population just stopped to populate values and there was no error message at all.

So I closed that workbook, rebooted the laptop, and started a new workbook with the very simple code that I got successful result on Sat.  Still, it's not working and it doesn't give me any error message.

Then, I tried the code on another laptop with a new excel workbook. On another laptop, the combo box is successfully populated with the values I want.

What's going on with my 1st laptop?  What can I do to make the combo box population work again?

The code is written in worksheet/Activate environment. Here is the code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Dim sh6 As Worksheet

    For Each sh6 In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Me.Test2_cbbox.AddItem sh6.name
    Next sh6

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the value when you type ?Application.EnableEvents in the immediate window?

Answer (score 1):

```
Me.Test2_cbbox.AddItem sh6.name
```

is the syntax for an `ActiveX` control

while if your combobox is a `Form` control, then use:

```
Me.Shapes("Test2_cbbox").ControlFormat.AddItem sh6.Name
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  But mine is a ActiveX control. By switching to "Me.Shapes("Test2_cbbox").ControlFormat.AddItem sh6.Name", I got run time error '438' saying that Object doesn't support this property or method. So I am still going to stick with the original code. But again, thank you for replying!

Comment: you are welcome. if your combobox is an ActiveX one and your code doesn't work with the proper syntax, then go and check as per @SNicolaou comment

Answer (score 0):

The link here identified my issue and suggest a few solutions.  The #13 post at edited Dec 16 '14 at 8:22 is the one that solve my problem.  Thank you all for helping.

[Microsoft Excel ActiveX Controls Disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled)

Comment: Well, the solution I posted on 10/7/19 worked for a week...Today my ActiveX controls again cannot function.....SOS!!