# Check Boxes (ActiveX Control) do not work anymore

Tags: excel, vba, office365, activex

Suddenly all the check boxes (ActiveX Control) in my Excels stopped to work. This concerns both new files as well as the old ones I've been using for years. I cannot (un)tick them and even if I do so manually in Properties, their functionality (e.g. hiding columns) seems to be broken.

I'm using the MS Office 365 ProPlus. I cannot say when the last update happened as they are fully automatic.

Comment: Had the same thing happen to me. I just deleted the existing activeX control and re-added it.Worked fine for me, but I only use the calendar picker.

Comment: @TimNevins: Unfortunately I have this problem with all controls. Even new ones in completely new files.

Comment: Active X controls on worksheets are buggy. Generally, you want to use Form controls instead.

Comment: @SmileyFtW: I've tried to replace them by the Form Controls. But they seem to not have the functionality I need. E.g. if you tick a checkbox some column hides. Or ticking one checkbox immediately unticks another one.
Any solution here?

Comment: @SmileyFtW: Ok, I've found a solution. Instead of Private Sub directly in the sheet it works rather well as Public in separate module.

Comment: Form controls don't have a click event per se. They are assigned a macro to run on. The macro assigned could look like a click procedure and then call private procedures in the module in accordance with the rules for Public/Private/Friend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Excel ActiveX Controls Disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411399/microsoft-excel-activex-controls-disabled)

Answer (score 1):

A silly problem is that it seems not to work on extended displays. I open the excel file in my laptop, and I can only check it in my laptop display.